# Auxiliary exercise to help my inverted rows to progress

Tags: strength-training, back, strength-gain, barbell-rows

Apart from some light auxiliary RTC work, my workouts consist of bodyweight squats, inverted rows and push ups, the two latter in the form of lighter versions on the bar of a Smith machine.

I have been steadily making progress by increasing reps from 3x3 to 3x15, then lowering the Smith bar and starting again with 3x3... But I started today a new inverted row cycle by lowering one step the bar and trying 3x3 and failed. It is simply too hard. Going back by raising the bar a step and 3x15 makes not much sense, I think, since I am already able to do that (In fact that is what I did after seeing that the new level was impossible).

Should I add one auxiliary exercise? (Dumbbell bentover row / Barbell row / Cable seated row are some options I am thinking of, as well as something more vertical like the lat pulldown machine). Or should I simply insist and keep on trying until achieving 3x3 perfect-form, slow repetitions? - I would like to maintain the workout length to a minimum in order to stay away from overtraining and to focus my body resources on making progress in a few basic exercises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I started today a new inverted row cycle by lowering one step the bar and trying 3x3 and failed. It is simply too hard. Going back by raising the bar a step and 3x15 makes not much sense, I think, since I am already able to do that

I think the training variables you can control are intensity, volume, and muscles worked. Since increasing the intensity (and *slightly* changing the muscles worked, by changing the angle) didn't work, try increasing the volume even more. Try 3x20 at the easier angle, or 3x15 with 10-second holds at the top on the last rep, or every fifth rep.

The other option, which I would try simultaneously to increased volume, is to get in as many reps as possible using the harder angle. If you have to do singles, do singles. If you have to rest five minutes between sets, OK. If you have to do partials or negatives, OK. As long as you're getting a solid base number of reps (at least 3x15) on the easier bar position, you'll be OK doing minimal volume with the harder version, which will help you get used to it.

Comment: That is, I might go up to 3x20 of the high bar version, followed by attempting 3x3 of the low bar version until I am able to achieve a decent volume of the hard version. At least that way I won't become deconditioned due to the low volume. It seems sound. Thanks!

Comment: That's not exactly what I said. It's unlikely that after failing at lower-height 3x3 you'll be able to do it after 3x20 of the easier. What I'm saying is after a warm-up, do **something** on the lower-height bar: singles or doubles or negatives or whatever allows you to confidently get the reps in. Then follow that with 3x15 or 3x18 or 3x20 or 3x15 with static holds on the easier height to make sure you're getting plenty of volume.

Comment: I understand. I think I will stick to 3x15 to keep some fuel in the back, followed by negatives and partial reps and such of the heavy version.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do the 3x15 first?

Comment: I am sorry, I said it the wrong way. I mean, I will do the attempts with lower bar first until completing the total number of reps anyhow, followed by the 3x15 high-bar rows, restricted to 3x15 to avoid too much volume in a single session. I wrote the opposite order, it was a mistake. Thanks for your help.

Comment: After some soreness and food craving I waited a couple of days and hit the gym again yesterday. I did 3, 4 and 5 reps of the harder version, so I guess my body has adapted or something.

Comment: Food is anabolic. Unless you're trying to lose fat weight, don't deprive yourself.

Comment: I want to avoid entering into detailed macronutrients tracking, but it is more and more evident that there is no other way of gaining strength while not gaining fat. I have allowed myself to eat more than usual in these last three days, and I really noticed the difference today at the gym (14 reps in total as said, instead of the 9 I was hoping to cranck out, and I didn't mention the other exercises, in which I could do more than expected as well).

Comment: @Mephisto Are you trying to lose fat/weight? Are you vegetarian, counting calories, or otherwise restricting food intake, and if so for how long?

Comment: I don't count calories. I simply try to follow a lifelong habit of no fast carbs or refined wheat, no sugar, no alcohol, lots of fruits and some vegetables, olive oil, fish and lean meat and I try to include some extra protein in all meals (a couple of extra egg whites and ham during breakfast, sardines during dinner, meat or fish at lunch time, post-workout low-fat milk with some honey, and some yoghurt). I watch my weight and cut down a bit on carbs when it rises. But lately with strength training it is difficult not to be hungry and not to gain weight at the same time.

Comment: I wanted to avoid counting calories or tracking down grams of protein, carbs and others in each meal, but I am afraid there is no other way. Well, I am going to ask a new question about choosing between trying to gain strength while not gaining fat vs bulking up first and thereafter loosing weight.

Answer (score 3):

The [barbell row](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/BackGeneral/BBBentOverRow.html) really is a terrific exercise right up until (for me) you start going over your bodyweight. So if you're 180lb, having 180lb's of bar+plates tends to be pretty heavy primarily because you're probably already doing a lot of other lower back exercises.

A big advantage to barbell lifts (vs bodyweight) is that you can incrementally change your weights and really tweak the volume vs intensity vs reps vs sets. The angles stay nearly identical, versus what you're experiencing on your [inverted (supine) row](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/BackGeneral/BWSupineRow.html). With inverse rows your pull angle is changing as you move the bar up and down.

Eventually, you will plateau strength with bodyweight training. [Pistols squats](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Quadriceps/BWSingleLegSquat.html) are awesome, but your body only weighs so much and you get more efficient at doing them as you progress so they become easier. You can put a weighted vest or backpack on, but now that's not bodyweight training anymore.

Boiled down, I'd recommend these points:

- The inverted (supine) row is for total novices. Once you have sufficient strength to move to "real" rows, you should. It's not that inverse rows are bad, they're just not as good as barbell rows, [dumbbell row](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/BackGeneral/DBBentOverRow.html)s, or [cleans](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/OlympicLifts/Clean.html).
- If you want to stay with inverse rows, you can [work negatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentric_training) a lot to build strength at angles that you can't quite nail on the way up. This is commonly done for folks who can't quite nail a pullup yet.
- If you're making steady progress in those areas as stated, you really might want to consider moving to [Starting Strength](http://startingstrength.wikia.com/wiki/The_Starting_Strength_Novice/Beginner_Programs) or [Strong Lifts](http://stronglifts.com/5x5/).

Comment: Oh, great! Yes, negative reps! I hadn't thought about it! Negative reps what I might need at this point. As for SS / SL5x5, that might be in the future, I must reach fully horizontal inverted rows and pull ups before. Thanks!